# Why i cannot set this key into $_SESSION?

Tags: php, linux, session

i have the following question. 
I use a network script (social engine) for my little homepage. When i am logged in, it sets the default $_SESSION keys below:

```
array(
['__default'] =>
array(  
['session.counter'] => 7
['session.timer.start'] => 1314860302
['session.timer.now'] => 1314860677
['user_email'] => '740dc176ae3c650327f94ab327916c07'
['user_pass'] => '3486851c47c9e92c72725a1046d87288'
['user_persist'] => FALSE
['user_id'] =>  2
)
['user_id'] =>
['user_id2'] => 3
)
```

I program on my Windows machine (xampp) there i have no problem to do sth. like this `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 2;`

I know, normally i should not use the same key even though it is not in the same layer, but i used it... (next time i will not)

I would like to understand why on the online vserver (linux) with the same files, `$_SESSION['user_id'] =>` is always  empty. I can never set it. Setting sth. like `$_SESSION['user_id2'] = 3;` is no problem (ok is another key).

I really do not have any clue why. Sadly the admin there also do not have an idea to solve this.

Is there a setting in the php config or sth. i must activate to get the same behavior on both machines?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

ruvenm

---

Ok i found the solution. register_globals is on for the vserver. After deactivating it, it works. Thought this setting will be deprecated?

Comment: there is no way why key names would matter, as long as you dont overwrite the same "layer". it somehow clears the session between reloads. Its not a "linux thing" but more of a thing you didn't take into account.. re-check your code touching that part of the session

Comment: yes i did that many times. i did not find sth. which could prevent this. On my windows machine it works without any problem. The same files are on both machines. So i think there is sth. wrong with the vserver. But what ???

Comment: Empty or is the key not set at all?

Comment: key is set, but value is empty as you can see above. I searched around and found out that register_globals is on for the vserver. On my machine it is off. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Search your sources for `user_id` and `$_SESSION['user_id']`, they may be used elsewhere.

Comment: hi. Yes it is used in the login to set the user_id in the ___default  SESSION. There is only one line of code where i set the `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 2;`. But its value in $_SESSION is always empty.